# Changing position of an image depending on screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm involved in a project of setting up a responsive website and have encountered a problem with which I can't find the answer here or anywhere else:

When viewing a specific box with text and an image I want the image to be positioned differently when using desktop/tablet and smaller screens (i.e. smartphones). On desktop/tablet I want the image to have a fixed size and float right beside the text but under the headline, on smaller screens I want the image to be on top above the headline and the text and fill up the box with 100% size.

In fact, it might be easier to show it with some pictures:

**How it looks like on desktop/tablet**
[image]

**How I want it to look like on smaller screens**

[image]

**The (undesired) result on smaller screens with the code I've done**
[image]

As you can see I have not figured out how to do this, with the result the headline and text gets covered by the image, and it does not respect the boundaries of the box. This is the code I've tried:

**The CSS for desktop/tablet:**

```
div {position: relative;}

div img {
width: 200px;
float: right;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-bottom: 20px;}
```

**The CSS for smaller screens:**

```
div {position: relative;}

div img {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 20px;}
```

**And the HTML for the div:**

```
<div>
<h2>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste</h2>
<img src="img/blossom.jpg">
Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.
</div>
```

Some notes: colors, fonts etc. are declared in a global CSS but are not important to this problem. The desktop/tablet version is working fine, its when the screen gets smaller and the smartphone version loads the image doesn't work as it should. Without the image, the small version works fine.

But the big question here is: how do I move the image with CSS to come above all text, including the headline, when the small screen version loads. The image must respect the width of the box and the text to go under.

Believe me, I've tried out a lot of different approaches with no luck so far, and I'm stuck! Perhaps the solution is very obvious and simple but I can't figure it out. Sure hope someone knows what to do...?

Comment: Have you checked out media queries?

Comment: I have, and I'm using media queries to use different stylesheets depending on screen size...

Comment: So what is the problem then? Just put the desired styling in the correct media queries and you are done.

Comment: As you can see I need to place the image between the headline and the text so it floats right but under the headline. My problem is that I cant make the image move to come on top, i.e. above the headline. Perhaps you know something about declaring images that I dont, in that case please give me a hint of where to put the image so its positioned beside the text but under the headline on big screens and above everything on small screens...

Answer (score 0):

If you would give the width of the pixels it would do the trick. If you want to use it to make it responsive you need to use media queries, like here.

```
@media (min-height: 680px), screen and (orientation: portrait) {
div {position: relative;}

div img {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
width: 200px;
margin-bottom: 20px;}
}
```

Cause now you use use the complete width of the image, not the screen.

Comment: Thank you, but I've already tried that! The image still doesnt respect the text, that is the headline and text are being covered by the image instead of being placed under it. And for design purposes I want the image width to cover the box within the box's margins.

Comment: and you are using media queries?

Comment: Yes different CSS for big screens and small screens. The problem is that in the HTML I need to place the IMG tag between the headline and the text in order for it to float right beside the text but under the headline. What I i.e. want is to move it above all text, incl headline, on small screens.